# Creating ActiveX on PowerPoint using Visual Studio Tools for Office

Tags: c#, vsto, activex, powerpoint

I am creating a `PowerPoint 2010` add-in created with the help of `Visual Studio Tools for Office`.

This add-in helps the user to create charts and customize them easily. It also provides a custom menu on right clicking or double clicking the chart. I tried to use the `Application.WindowBeforeRightClick` and `Application.WindowBeforeDoubleClick` events provided by PowerPoint but they don't get fired(because of a bug that Microsoft hasn't fixed since PowerPoint 2007).

Now, in order to show my custom menus I am thinking of making an `ActiveX` control and embed it on my PowerPoint slide. This control will interact with the mouse for events like `MouseOver`, `MouseUp`, `MouseDown`, `WindowBeforeDoubleClick`, `WindowBeforeRightClick` etc.

I am not sure if this is possible. If it is then how to write an ActiveX control for PowerPoint in VSTO environment using C#? Also how to make it invisible and responsive at the same time?

Comment: In general, ActiveX controls on PPT slides are only active when in SlideShow view, so this may be a non-starter for you.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, thanks for the reply.
Can you tell any other way in which I can listen to mouse events in the presentation/designer view.

Comment: Other than trapping the selection change event, none that I know of, and I don't think that'll do for what you're after.

Comment: Can this be done using a mouse hook?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can hook the mouse, there are libraries out there that make this easy.

One I've tried is "MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor" - searching for that on the web should provide a link.

It has an "AppHook" rather than a "GlobalHook" so you can just listen to the PowerPoint editor window.

Comment: Can you place the important content of the link into the answer itself? Links can go dead.